# Issue with getResource() in JavaFX - FXML file not found

Tags: java, getresource

I'm having issue with gerResource().

```
public class MainApp extends Application {
...
    public void initRootLayout() {
        try {
            // load `rootLayout.fxml`
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("/proj/addapp/RootLayout.fxml"));
            rootLayout = loader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();

            // ...
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
...
```

I have `RootLayout.fxml` file in `proj.addapp` package along with `MainApp`, but it seems fxml can't be found. I've been looking for awhile but wasn't able to find the answer.

I've tried different pathway and rebuild the project.

Comment: The code seems fine so far. I think, we'll probably need your exact project structure in order to debug further. One alternative though: If `MainApp.class` and `RootLayout.fxml` are at the same location, you can also use a relative path for `Class#getResource()`, which in this case is simply `RootLayout.fxml`. That eliminates the path as a potential cause of error.